# Error reading excel file and save it in SoapUI's Test suite properties

Tags: groovy, soapui, jxl

Trying to read data from excel file and save it in Test suite properties, but getting this error (Using SOAP UI 5.1.3)

//This is the code

```
import java.io.*
import jxl.*
def file =new File("D:\\GroovyTest\\Example.xls")
def wb=Workbook.getWorkbook(file)
def sheet=wb.getSheet("Sheet1")
r=sheet.getRows()
for(int i=1;i<2;i++)
{
    Cell c1=sheet.getCell(0,i)
    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.addProperty("CityName"+i)
    String cityName =c1.getContents()
    testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setProperty("CityName"+i,cityName)
    testRunner.runTestStepByName("GetSupplierByCity")   
}
```

this is Error:

> Error: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:  com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite.setProperty() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [CityName1, New York] Possible solutions: getProperty(java.lang.String), addProperty(java.lang.String), hasProperty(java.lang.String), hasProperty(java.lang.String), getProject(), getProperties() error at line: 12

Comment: Ameya, please check the solution and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to get it.

As the error says, there is no such method `setProperty`.

In order to set either new property or modify existing property, use just `setPropertyValue` method.

So, all you need to do is simple. Remove below statement from your code.

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.addProperty("CityName"+i)
```

And change below statement

**From:**

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setProperty("CityName"+i,cityName)
```

**To:**

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.setPropertyValue("CityName"+i,cityName)
```

Comment: @Ameyapagore, appreciate if you can [accept this as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thank you! very much for the solution.